# Angular 1.6 in Dashboard widget

Tags: plugin-development, dashboard-widgets

Is there a clean way to use angular in a dashboard widget for Craft 3 or craft 2? When the widget is created I can use it after a site refresh with no problems but I don't know if there is a hook or some kind of a javascript callback after the html is loaded so I can use my `$compile` function.

I'm not that experienced with angular yet so maybe my question is wrong here but since I'm able to run angular after every other dynamic html change I want to ask here. I know I can use this function in order to compile the template

```
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(
    [
        "$compile", function ($compile) {
            var scope = angular.element(document).scope();
            $compile(document)(scope);
            scope.$apply();
         }
    ]
);
```

But I need some callback event to fire it